# Specifying a document element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to reveal a hidden part of an input form when a specific value is chosen in an earlier part.

Why does this Javascript work

```
  function unhideRecipient() {
    var recipDiv = document.getElementById("recipientDetails");
    // recipient1 = document.getElementById("recipient1");   // ?????
    if (recipient1.value == "0") {                           // ?????
      recipDiv.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      recipDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Given this HTML

```
<form>
  <label>Recipient:</label>
  <select name="recip1" id="recipient1" onchange="unhideRecipient()">
    <option value="1">Alice Doe</option>
    <option value="2">Bobby Poe</option>
    <option value="3">Clive Roe</option>
    <option value="0">Other ...</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <div id="recipientDetails">
    <label>Name:</label>       <input type="text"> <br />
    <label>StreetName:</label> <input type="text"> <br />
    <label>City:</label>       <input type="text"> <br />
  </div>
</form>
```

With this style

```
  label { display: inline-block; width: 6em; text-align: right; }
  div#recipientDetails { display: none; }
```

I had expected to need the commented out variable assignment in the Javascript but it seems to work just using the elements `id` attribute value as if it were an object name.

Am I misunderstanding - and where can I read more about this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydgpML

Comment: Browsers put references to DOM elements with id values into the global scope as variables (`window` properties). It's a thing that IE started a long time ago. It's a terrible idea but here we are.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.